# What should BDD be written for?

Tags: bdd, agile, user-stories, epic

My Proj Manager asked me to write a BDD.
What should a BDD written for ?
Should we write a BDD for each Story or for each epic ?

Comment: "Write a BDD" does not make sense to me because BDD is a process.

Answer (score 1):

Normally (there are, as always, exceptions), you start by writing your *user stories* in a format that BDD tools can read (a format similar to the [Gherkin language](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin)). The user stories can then be implemented and executed by the tools as tests.

A programming language neutral intro to BDD can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development).

Answer (score 1):

BDD is Behavior Driven Development. As a result, you have a specification that can be executed via some testing framework, thus ensuring requirement completion. Each User Story usually has several scenarios. Here is an example from our project:

```
Given Bug (Task, User Story, Feature) view
When I expand 'Actions' menu
Then I see 'Attach to Request' link above the 'Move and Copy' action
When I click 'Attach to Request' link
then I see requests lookup
[image of the lookup]
```

It is better to create scenarios that can be automated. It is challenging, but doable. Here is the more complete example of BDD scenarios:

http://www.targetprocess.com/blog/2009/10/bdd-and-user-story-specification-examples.html

Even with simple Given -> When -> Then format you have a good structure for your user stories, so it is worth to use this format without automation. Still automation is a huge benefit that BDD provides.

Comment: BDD tools != BDD. You don't need a special BDD tool to do BDD. Many consider [BDD to be TDD done right](http://dannorth.net/2012/05/31/bdd-is-like-tdd-if/) (although Dan North clarifies his intent).

Comment: When did I mention tools? Can you read?

Comment: Yes I can, you described it as, "form of specification that can be executed via some testing framework". That is just wrong. That is what BDD tools are for.

Comment: Quote from Wikipedia. " the practice of BDD does assume the use of specialized software tools to support the development process.[2] Although these tools are often developed specifically for use in BDD projects, they can be seen as specialized forms of the tooling that supports test-driven development. "

Comment: @DaveHillier We use BDD in our project quite heavily (not a little less than before, but still). It is a more high-level than TDD and I personally think it is quite useless without automation. If you can't execute the scenarios, you are not doing BDD. If you can't execute unit test, you are not doing TDD.

Comment: Go back to wikipedia and read the first line. That contradicts what you wrote. BDD is a process, it is not a specification. The output of BDD is a specification.

Comment: @DaveHillier I agree :)

Comment: @MichaelDubakov Having focused entirely on the conversations with a number of clients now, I challenge the assertion that "it's quite useless without automation". If you're not *having conversations*, you're not doing BDD. I consider shallow BDD to be only having the conversations; you can deepen it by automating, but conversations around scenarios should always be the first practice adopted. I miss JBehave1, the first ever BDD tool that I helped Dan North write. It was perfect, in that nobody ever used it; it just drove the right conversations.